# Proper use of super in Python -- should I reference the class name explicitly?

Tags: python, python-2.7, class-hierarchy

```
class Foo(object):
    def whee(self):
        return 77

class Bar(Foo):
    def whee(self):
        return super(Bar, self).whee() + 1

class Baz(Foo):
    def whee(self):
        return super(self.__class__, self).whee() + 1
```

Both `Bar` and `Baz` return the same result for `whee()`. I'm used to the syntax in `Bar`. Is there any reason I shouldn't use the syntax in `Baz`?

Comment: Never pass `self.__class__` to `super`. If it was that simple, `super` never would have required that argument in the first place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there any reason I shouldn't use the syntax in `Baz`?

**Yes, there is a reason you shouldn't use that syntax.**  If you subclass from `Baz`, the `super()` call will resolve back to `Baz.whee()` and you'll get stuck in an infinite loop.  This also applies to the syntax `super(type(self), self).whee()`.

(Well, actually you will blow the recursion limit and error out.  But either way it's a problem.)

Comment: Oh. oops, that makes sense.

Comment: ...so I guess that means class methods don't have any way of accessing the class they're declared in, unless you explicitly reference that class?

Comment: @JasonS: Yes, that's why Python 3 had to add a "secret" `__class__` local variable holding that info.  It's how the zero-args `super()` works.

Comment: It's actually possible to access the `__class__` variable explicitly on Python 3 (and it's even documented), but it's not really encouraged, and people will get confused.